# simple MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables.

```
CLIENTS
JOBS
INVOICES
```

I need to see every row in the INVOICES table between such and such a date grouped by day, showing the related JOBID and which client (by name) is connected. The invoices are connected to the clients by the JOB ID only.

Does this make sense?

```
SELECT
    j.ID As JobID,
    CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME, ' ', c.LASTNAME) As ClientName,
    c.ID As ClientID
    i.DATE
    i.LENSES
    i.FRAMES
    i.TAXABLEGOODS
    i.DISCOUNT
    i.PAYMENT
    i.PAYMENTTYPE
    i.PREVIOUSBALANCE
FROM
    JOBS j,
    CLIENTS c,
    INVOICES i,
WHERE
    i.JOBID = j.ID
    j.CLIENTID = c.ID
GROUP BY DATE
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about using:

```
WHERE your_date between first_date AND last_date GROUP BY YEAR(your_date), MONTH(your_date), DAY(your_date);
```